# How to split a file path to get the file name?

Tags: java, android, split

I have this string in my Android Application:

```
/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg
```

I need manipulate the string and to split the string for this output:

```
temp.jpg
```

I need always take the last element of the string.

How to this output in java?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Comment: I notice you've accepted one of the string splitting answers as your preferred answer. Do check the duplicate I've suggested, since you should be using `File` for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

one another possibility:

```
String lStr = "/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg";
lStr = lStr.substring(lStr.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
System.out.println(lStr);
```

Comment: This produces the output `/temp.jpg` since substring is inclusive, and this is not the output that OP desires. In lieu of editing this answer, I would recommend accepting the answer that uses `File` instead.

Answer (score 39):

### This is not a string splitting exercise

If you need to get a **file name** from a **file path**, use the [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class:

```
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Output:

```
temp.jpg
```

Comment: Coming from a C++ background, using File just to substr is kind of a turn off for me. I mean, it's very inefficient and you need to instantiate an object just to do a trivial thing.

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra it may not be trivial if the path uses different kind of separators based on the OS.

Comment: Exactly. Always use the built-in tools until your careful instrumentation shows this is the crux of your performance issues.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with string split: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

```
String string = "/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
String file= parts[parts.length-1];
```

Comment: Don't hard code 4 he may have different lengths try parts.length - 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String path= "/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg";
String[] parts = path.split("/");
String filename;
if(parts.length>0)
    filename= parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "/storage/emulated/0/temp.jpg";
String[] splitString = null;
splitString = string.split("/");
splitString[splitString.length - 1];//this is where your string will be
```

Try using the String function split.  It splits the string by your input and returns an array of strings.  Just access the last element of the array in your case.