# How to Remove Absolute Path From File?

Tags: java, file, jtree

As I understand it, `file.getAbsolutePath()` gets the full path for a file. I thought `file.getAbsoluteFile()` would just get the file name, and *not* the path, but that didn't work. Basically I want to display the files and directories in a `JTree`, but for obvious reasons, I don't want the path. Just the name. How can I get this done?

Comment: Check the answer by Duncan Jones in [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019132/how-to-split-a-file-path-to-get-the-file-name)

Comment: Also please use a [basic Google search strategy of this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+to+get+the+basic+file+name+site:stackoverflow.com) (please check link) before asking a likely duplicate question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (and/or read the Javadoc of the class you're using)

Comment: @AndyTurner: indeed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()):

> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. This is just the last name in the pathname's name sequence.